# How to save different objects with one post request in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, post, sequelize.js

This seems like a very basic thing to do but I can't really find the proper way of doing it. My Node/Express/Sequelize project essentially will save a single user search (to the Searches table) and one or more links from the search result (to the Results table). The user searches, gets results, selects the results they find helpful, then hit a save button to save both the search query and the chosen results.

A Search has many Results so the Result object will have a foreign key of searchId (which makes me think that the Search object needs to be saved first to have an id to place on each Result object). So far, I can successfully save a Search item with the following code:

**controllers/search.js**

```
const Search = require('../models').Search;

module.exports = {
    create(req, res) {
        return Search
        .create({
          text: req.body.search_text  
        })
        .then(search => res.status(201).send(search))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    } };
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const searchController = require('../controllers').search;
const resultController = require('../controllers').result;
const axios = require('axios');
const bingWebSearch = require('../helpers/bingWebSearh')

module.exports = (app) => {

    //some app.get requests here;

    app.post('/search/results', searchController.create);
};
```

That one `app.post` should save the Search to the searches table and also save the (possibly) multiple Results to the results table with that Search objects id as an association. How should I be handling this? Should it be in one `app.post` request or should it be split into two where the first saves the Search and then somehow moves on to a second `app.post` request to handle the Results (and also passes in the id from the newly created Search object)?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the http endpoint (either GET/POST/DELETE etc) configured acts as an interface between the server and the client for some sort of communication.

Unless, you require a feedback/input from the client you can handle the processing logic as part of one endpoint only. In your case, `/search/results` endpoint can persist data in the two tables as part of a single endpoint call. Obviosly, you will make the code modular and keep the logic as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: So you're saying to create a control flow within the POST request to handle each save? For example, holding `search` object as a variable, then set an `if` statement that saves the variable. If the variable saves, move on to saving the `result` objects passing in the search variables newly created id?

Comment: Not a control flow. If the business logic is different, you should have different endpoints. I am saying the subsequent logic of saving your search object should be in the same endpoint, may be a part of a promise chain.